# measure the latency/delay with ICMP (ping)

Tags: linux, ping, icmp

How to measure latency (not rtt) using ICMP (ping) on linux ?

> The Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP) is a supporting protocol in the Internet protocol suite.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/984306/linux-ping-command-getting-rtt

Comment: Not rtt but delay (latency)

Comment: the rtt is used to calculate the latency

Comment: using linux ? how ?

Comment: read the link and look for rtt

Comment: What is your definition of latency? One-way or computational latency? If the first: divide the values by 2, assuming that send and return path are roughly the same.

Answer (score 0):

`ping -U <remote-address>` for IPv4 or `ping6 -U <remote-address>` for IPv6

Comment: Not rtt but delay (latency)

Comment: changed the answer. The parameter for this is `-U` ("Print  full  user-to-user latency")